# Parity of even determinants

Tags: combinatorics, determinant

If $n$ is odd, then is the number of $0-1$ matrices whose determinant is odd, almost always an odd value?

Above seems to be wrong:

The number of non-singular determinants over $\Bbb F_2$ is even. Does this indicate parity of number of odd determinants or permanents over $\Bbb R$ is even?

Comment: The question needs to be reworded so that one can be sure how to interpret it. Do you mean "For odd $n$, is the number of $0-1$ matrices having odd determinant almost always odd?"

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) have you checked this for small values?  I haven't.  2) since determinants of transposes are equal, we only need to look at symmetric $0-1$ matrices, which can be thought of as adjacency matrices of undirected graphs. Determinants of adjacency matrices have a lot of interpretations, but none of them is telegraphing an answer to this question to me.

Comment: It seems unless I miscalculated.

Answer (score 3):

$$\#\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_2)=(2^n-1)(2^n-2)(2^n-4)\cdot\ldots\cdot(2^n-2^{n-1})$$
hence:
$$\nu_2\left(\#\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_2)\right) = 1+2+\ldots+(n-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
and the number of $0-1$ matrices with odd determinant (i.e. invertible) is a multiple of $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$.

Comment: What is value denotation $\nu_2$?

Comment: @Turbo: $$\nu_2(m)=\max\{\eta\in\mathbb{N}:2^\eta\mid m\}$$

Comment: So the conclusion is that the number of such $0$--$1$ matrices is never odd, for $n>1$.

Comment: Is there another derivation? Is similar to my guess.